# How to make a sidebar and set the values in specific cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a sheet in which I can set the value in specific cells using the sidebar.

Example: There is a sidebar in with 4 fields i.e., **Username, Password, Day and Time** and in the sheet I have set the heders like A1 for Username, A2 for Password, A3 for Day and A4 for Time now whenever I enter the data it reflects in sheet-like

**Username is in A1** then the input is in **B1 is Sumit Singh (Data filled by sidebar)**

**Password is in A2** then the input is in **B2 is sumit (Data filled by sidebar)**

**Day is in A3** then the input is in **B3 is Monday (Data filled by sidebar)**

**Time is in A4** then the input is in **B4 is 10 (Data filled by sidebar)**

I have already tried some codes but they append the row and I want data in specific cells only. Like I want data entered by sidebar like **username only set value in b1, password only set value in b2, day only set value in b3 and time only set value in b4.**

[The structure of the sidebar attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdkmR.jpg)
[Data in sheet will look like the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1uyh.jpg)

Codes are....

```js
var SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

function showUserForm() {
  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("userform");
  
  var html = template.evaluate();
  html.setTitle("User Form Basics");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function errorMessage(){
  Browser.msgBox("Name & Phone are required");
}

function setNameValue(nameData){
  return SHEET.getRange(1, 2).setValue(nameData);
}

function setPasswordValue(passwordData){
  return SHEET.getRange(2, 2).setValue(passwordData);
}

function setdayValue(dayData){
  return SHEET.getRange(3, 2).setValue(dayData);
}

function settimeValue(timeData){
  return SHEET.getRange(4, 2).setValue(timeData);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
<label for="username">Username</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="pass" type="password" class="validate">
<label for="pass">Password</label>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<select id="day">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
<option value="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="Friday">Friday</option>
<option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>
<label>Select Day</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<select id="time">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<label>Select Time</label>
</div>
</div>


<div class="input-field col s12">
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="btn">Add
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
</div>



</div><!--END ROW -->

</div>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->


<script>
var nameBox = document.getElementById("username");

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);
function addRecord (){

var name = nameBox.value;
var nameData = {
name : nameBox.value
};

google.script.run.setNameValue(nameData);

} //CLOSE ADD RECORD


</script>

<script>
var passwordBox = document.getElementById("pass");
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);
function addRecord (){
var password = passwordBox.value;
var passwordData = {
password : passwordBox.value
};
google.script.run.setPasswordValue(passwordData);

} //CLOSE ADD RECORD


</script>

<script>
var dayBox = document.getElementById("day");
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);
function addRecord (){
var day = dayBox.value;
var dayData = {
day : dayBox.value
};
google.script.run.setdayValue(dayData);

} //CLOSE ADD RECORD


</script>

<script>
var timeBox = document.getElementById("time");
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);
function addRecord (){
var time = timeBox.value;
var timeData = {
time : timeBox.value
};
google.script.run.settimeValue(timeData);

} //CLOSE ADD RECORD


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts (including links to related questions on this site) as is suggested in [ask] as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Rubén. I have attached my code. Kindly check and please help.

Comment: Your client-side code is calling `setPhoneValue` but the server side code doesn't include a function with that name.

Comment: Regarding `setNameValue` your client side code is passing an object but `setValue` requires only supports string, number and Date objects. If your code is throwin an error please add the explicit error to question. In the mean time, I voted to open the question.

Comment: Hi Rubén, Thanks a lot for correcting me. Now I'm able to get the data in relevant cells but the issue is when I submit the username sumit it shows {name=sumit} and same for other files too. Every submission includes **{name=sumit}**. Please guide me on how can I remove **{name=}**. I have also updated the codes. Kindly check and help.

Comment: Stack Snippet should not be used for Google Apps Script code b/c it can’t be executed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Sidebar Buttons:

You can modify it as much as you wish.  It's setup to change the values of A1 through A5.

```
function simpleSideBar() {
  var html="";
  html+='<input type="text" id="txt1" /><input type="button" value="A1" onClick="update(this.value);" /><br />';
  html+='<input type="text" id="txt2" /><input type="button" value="A2" onClick="update(this.value);" /><br />';
  html+='<input type="text" id="txt3" /><input type="button" value="A3" onClick="update(this.value);" /><br />';
  html+='<input type="text" id="txt4" /><input type="button" value="A4" onClick="update(this.value);" /><br />';
  html+='<input type="text" id="txt5" /><input type="button" value="A5" onClick="update(this.value);" /><br />';
  html+='<script>';
  html+='const gids={"A1":"txt1","A2":"txt2","A3":"txt3","A4":"txt4","A5":"txt5"};';
  html+='function update(loc){const data=document.getElementById(gids[loc]).value;google.script.run.updateData({"location":loc,"value":data});}';
  html+='</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle("Sidebar Buttons"));
}

function updateData(obj) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(obj.location).setValue(obj.value);
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thanks but this form doesn't solve my issue. I want to submit all the data in a single click and in your solutions, you have created multiple buttons. I want a submit button in the end which saves all the data in selected cells. For reference see my codes and images. Please help.

Comment: You modify to use a form if you wish but I'm not interested in doing for you.

Comment: Hey Cooper, please don't get offended and thank you so much for your support.